# Aligning the text inside a <ul> list

Tags: html, css

How can I align the text inside my ul list?? I tried vertical-align: middle but it didnt work

I there any alternative for it??

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TBEnf/1/
Here is my code

```
<style>
.profilePicture {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    margin:5px;

}

.UploadPicture ul li a {
    display:table-cell;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;

}
.UploadPicture ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:block;
    background:#ff6a00;
}
.UploadPicture ul li:hover {
    background:#808080;
}
 .UploadPicture ul {
     display:table-row;
}
```

```
   <div class="UploadPicture">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Change Profile Picture</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Align the text *where*?

Comment: there is no `text-align: middle`, but `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: I mean vertical-allign sorry

Comment: @rodolfonavalon What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to center the text horizontally or vertically? Are you trying to center the whole list or what? Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `display:table-cell` from the `a` styling. Then `text-align:center` will work.

```
.UploadPicture ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;

}
.UploadPicture ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:block;
    background:#ff6a00;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also note that the syntax is text-align: *center*, not *middle*.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBEnf/2/).